# Subscribe to pull request comments with GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm creating a github app that tries to read a pull request comment and perform some actions based on it.

I already subscribed the app to the pull request, Pull request review comments and pull request review but my app is not called when i create a simple comment in the PR.

Do i have to do something else or github simple don't offer this?

PS: I tested with issue comments too and it works properly.

Comment: For regular comments, I believe you'll want to subscribe to the "Issue comment" event. Even in a pull request, regular comments that get posted in the main thread are called issue comments.

Comment: This is exactly the answer i was looking for. Thanks a lot @WilhelmKlopp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by [@wilhelm-klopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2162900/wilhelm-klopp)

> For regular comments, I believe you'll want to subscribe to the "Issue
> comment" event. Even in a pull request, regular comments that get
> posted in the main thread are called issue comments.

Solved my problem